# can't start eclipse for PHP 21-12

Tags: php, eclipse, startup

I downloaded eclipse 20-12 for PHP, but I am unable to start it. I'm running Windows 10 with jre1.8.0_321 and jdk17.0.2.  On start up I get an error message to review a configuration log file which I do not know how to interpret.
The log file is attached:
`

```
!SESSION 2022-02-15 15:14:45.977 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.22.0.I20211124-1800
java.version=1.8.0_321
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_CA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2022-02-15 15:14:46.415
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator [2]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.lambda$1(ModuleContainer.java:1834)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1829)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1777)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1739)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.startWorker(SystemModule.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:251)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-02-15 15:14:46.415
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.4.0.v20210315-2228.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2022-02-15 15:14:46.415
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator [2]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-02-15 15:14:46.428
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

`

Comment: You Java 8 JRE is taking precedence over the Java 17 JDK for some reason. Eclipse needs at least Java 11 to run.

Comment: What nitind says. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by simply uninstalling the jre 1.8, so that the Program Files\java folder contains only jkd17.0.2.